# possible to get an SVG from an SVG spritesheet

Tags: svg

I am using https://github.com/alexjlockwood/ShapeShifter for animated SVGs. It seems to export a SVG spritesheet (many SVG files instead of one) rather than a single SVG.

Is it possible to go from an SVG spritesheet(s) to a single SVG, like this

https://github.com/SamHerbert/SVG-Loaders/blob/master/svg-loaders/bars.svg

Comment: This is not an SVG spritesheet. It's an animated SVG. You can copy the code from github, and remove the `<animate>` elements. If the result is not what you are looking for play with the `height` and the `y` attributes of every `<rect>` keeping in mind that if you add 5 units to the `y` you have to rest 5 units from the `height`

Comment: @enxaneta the SamHerbet is an example of what I need, not what I have. ShapeShifter will output your work as an SVG Spritesheet (e.g. one animation will export as like 5-10 SVG files for one animated icon). Hope this helps clarify.

Comment: In this case can you show us what you have?

Comment: Here is a little more info https://github.com/alexjlockwood/ShapeShifter/issues/315. What is the best way to share a file for stackoverflow?